# Example that seems to violate conservation of angular momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, torque

[image]
Mass m is rotating on a horizontal friction-less plane around a tiny hole. A massless string is connected to mass m and the other end of it is slowly pulled.

Taking the center as our origin we see that there are no torques on the body so the angular momentum is conserved.

When the body is at  the center the angular momentum will be zero since $r=0$ violating the conservation principle ?

What have I incorrectly done?

Comment: Thank you for the similar Q, It did help by showing that the speed will increase as the radius decreases however I wanted to know that will the speed really go to infinity when the body reaches the centre. It surprises me that it will. I hope someone will show how the integral of work goes to infinity as well.

Comment: If the forces are finite and there is no friction then the body will never get to the centre (assuming it starts off with some angular momentum). If there is friction then this can change the angular momentum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no friction, then in reality there is a limit to how far the mass $m$ can be pulled towards the hole.

$L = mvr$, so $$v=\frac{L}{mr}$$

The centripetal force needed to move the mass in a circle is $$F=\frac{mv^2}{r} = \frac{L^2}{mr^3}$$

So as the mass approaches the hole, and $r$ decreases, there will be a position where the force $F$ just provides the centripetal force and can't drag the mass any closer to the hole.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to realize, that speed of the mass increases to infinity as it approaches to the center:
$$L=mvr\Rightarrow v=\frac{L}{mr},$$
$L$ being the conserved angular momentum and $v$ velocity of the mass.
So $r$ approaching zero does not mean $L$ is approaching zero also.

Comment: It's quite unphyiscal for the speed to blow to infinity!

Comment: @Kashmiri yes, it would either require infinite force or infinite time to bring the mass into the center. Your scenario $r=0$ cannot be done.

Comment: @Kashmiri massless strings and frictionless tables are also of course unphysical ;)

Comment: @Triatticus, indeed but they are good models in some cases and lead to good results but still this example surprised me. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the object has a finite mass, it also has a finite size. The horizontal string cannot bring the center of mass to a radius of zero.

Comment: We can think of it as a point particle.

Comment: Then you get to a relativistic velocity and mass.